# Android app force close after activity splashscreen

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging, android-volley

I have android project which includesto gcm, json, and volley library.

**Structure of the project as follows:**

14 min SDK API, compile SDK API version 23, the target SDK API 17.

The problem is, when the application runs on the Android API 17 application force close. but when run on API 23 all running normally. What there who can help solve this problem?

Comment: Need more clarifications + code.

Comment: add your code in Questions not in Answer. Also add Log.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya sorry i beginners here :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use background thread to download the JSON data.Use AsykTask or some other android threading mechnism to handle this.

Note: you should not block ui thraed by running time consuming task,once JSON data downloaded update the ui thread